# How do I add "angular.d.ts" to a standard IONIC project and use it in my "app.ts"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript

I am changing an IONIC app to use TypeScript. My app.js has

```
var app = angular.module('coreApp', ['ngCordova', 'ionic'])
```

Now I want to use type script in my project, I downloaded a fresh standard IONIC app IonicFramework.com and installed typescript for project.

But want to know the right way to add  "angular.d.ts" and "cordova.d.ts" in project, which should finally be included in app.ts as this:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/cordova/cordova.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Your `<reference/>` tags appear correct; are you asking for header files? If that's the case, there are TypeScript definition files for many JavaScript libraries at [Definitelytyped](http://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). They have definitions for Angular, Cordova and Cordova-IONIC. Simply downloading the files to the paths where your `<reference/>` tags expect them to be will work for the compiler, but I don't know what else you might need as I don't know which development environment you use.